# Spring Data JPA - ManyToOne null

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I'm learning Spring Data and JPA, and I have trouble making a simple ManyToOne - OneToMany connection within my entities.

Example: model relationship between cars and people (owners), one person can own multiple cars, but one car is owned by only one person.

Problem: owner of Car (annotated with ManyToOne) is always null.

App.java

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    @Autowired private PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired private CarRepository carRepository;

    @EventListener
    @Transactional
    public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        Car car1 = new Car();
        Car car2 = new Car();
        Person person = new Person();

        car1.setName("Ferrari");
        car2.setName("Porsche");
        person.setName("Person Name");

        carRepository.save(car1);
        carRepository.save(car2);

        person.getCars().add(car1);
        person.getCars().add(car2);

        personRepository.save(person);

        carRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);   // TODO owner should not be null
        personRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Car.java

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person owner;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Person getOwner() { return owner; }
    public void setOwner(Person owner) { this.owner = owner; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", owner=" + owner + "]";
    }

}
```

CarRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, UUID>  { }
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Set<Car> getCars() { return cars; }
    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) { this.cars = cars; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", cars=" + cars + "]";
    }

}
```

PersonRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, UUID>  { }
```

Output:

```
Car [id=10b38a23-536d-4b8f-8578-16e12f2f65d1, name=Ferrari, owner=null]
Car [id=2c15abf9-cb96-4d70-9271-b25096764276, name=Porsche, owner=null]
Person [id=8484b16f-1645-49af-a4d5-4b6ba7238aba, name=Person Name, cars=[Car [id=2c15abf9-cb96-4d70-9271-b25096764276, name=Porsche, owner=null], Car [id=10b38a23-536d-4b8f-8578-16e12f2f65d1, name=Ferrari, owner=null]]]
```

Owner of both cars is null. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is all in the context of a single transaction, with different repositories handling the saving, and no flushing, so I'm not sure that you can retrieve changes made by the personRepo from the carRepo. The simple answer is to just call `car.setOwner` and pass the person in. Otherwise you'll need to either use `flush`, use an `entityManager` instance instead of two separate repos, use the `personRepo` to retrieve the cars, or restructure your code to handle things in different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are `not setting the owner of the car via car.setOwner(...)`.

And also since you have `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` on the `OneToMany` annotation, you don't need to persist individual cars first and then the owner.

Just calling the `personRepository.save(person);` should be enough.

So with the above changes, you code :

```
            Car car1 = new Car();
            Car car2 = new Car();
            Person person = new Person();

            car1.setName("Ferrari");
            car2.setName("Porsche");
            person.setName("Person Name");
            person.getCars().add(car1);
            person.getCars().add(car2);
            car1.setOwner(person);
            car2.setOwner(person);

            personRepository.save(person);
```

And one more thing, you need to modify the toString method of `Car` object. Person object's toString is calling Car's toString which internally is calling `Person` toString again. This would lead to `StackOverflowException`. Consider not printing the entire `Person object` in the `Car toString()` method.

May be `Car [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", owner=" + owner.getName() + "]`

** UPDATE **

If you are looking for a specific solution where you want to ensure the Car owner is populated in DB without making a call to `car.setOwner(...)` method then you could update the `OneToMany` mapping as below:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="owner")
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();
```

Basically, `mappedBy` is the one which decides who is the owner of the bidirectional relationship. In the first case, you have mentioned ownership of the relationship is owned by `Car` entity via `mappedBy` attribute. So unless we set the owner on the car object the ORM will not populate the `owner` column.

With the second approach of removing the mappedBy, the `oneToMany` becomes the owner of the relationship and so once you add to the car list of the Person, that person id will be used as the owner and will be populated in the DB against the owner column of the Car.

But, in the second case, and extra update is fired to update the owner column, apart ftom the normal insert, and so the owner column should be nullable.

Comment: As I understand this is one of the few possible solutions. I will accept it if no more detailed answer will be given. Thanks for pointing out that no saving is needed because of CascadeType.ALL, and also the potential StackOverFlowException.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for a specific solution where you want to ensure the Car owner is populated in DB without making a call to `car.setOwner(...)` method? If so, you can have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: If I go with the first approach, (where Car owns the relationship), why is the person.getCars().add(car1) call also necessary?

Comment: Because the cascadeType.ALL is on the `OneToMany` field. Since we want persist on `Person` to propagate to elements in the Set we need to populate that. Else you would need to persist Person first and then call persist on individual cars.

Comment: After so many hours of wondering which annotation is wrong I finally found you comment thank you!